# Dimensional Modelling for Product and review system

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

I came across the below scenario where I need to convert an OLTP database system to a dimensional modelling or DWH system.

I received two files from source in JSON format. It does have Product and reviewer details.
Product : ID , name , price ,urlofproduct ,relatedproducts ,salesrank, brand, categories

```
Product data sample :
{
  "ID": "0000031852",
  "name": "Girls Ballet Tutu Zebra Hot Pink",
  "price": 3.17,
  "urlofproduct ": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51fAmVkTbyL._SY300_.jpg",
  "relatedproducts ":
  {
    "also_bought": ["B00JHONN1S", "B002BZX8Z6", "B00D2K1M3O", "0000031909"],
    "also_viewed": ["B002BZX8Z6", "B00JHONN1S", "B008F0SU0Y", "B00D23MC6W", "B00AFDOPDA"],
    "bought_together": ["B002BZX8Z6"]
  },
  "salesRank": {"Toys & Games": 211836},
  "brand": "Coxlures",
  "categories": [["Sports & Outdoors", "Other Sports", "Dance"]]
}
```

Reviewer : ID, ProductID, Name, helpful, reviewtext, overall, summary, unixreviewtime, reviewtime

Reviewer sample data :

```
{
  "ID": "A2SUAM1J3GNN3B",
  "ProductID": "0000013714",
  "Name": "J. McDonald",
  "helpful": [2, 3],
  "reviewText": "I bought this for my husband who plays the piano.  He is having a wonderful time playing these old hymns.  The music  is at times hard to read because we think the book was published for singing from more than playing from.  Great purchase though!",
  "overall": 5.0,
  "summary": "Heavenly Highway Hymns",
  "unixReviewTime": 1252800000,
  "reviewTime": "09 13, 2009"
}
```

I am struggling how dimensionally model it. I can see product and reviewer are the two dimensions.
But how should I store the related products bought, viewed or bought_together in my data warehouse.

Can any one please help with this. just give some idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL Server then you can try using the OPENJSON (SQL Server) function . This function allows Parse and Transform JSON Data.